# Will my 320W PSU handle a Asus GTX 750Ti

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I've got a 320W PSU as far as I know and it's a Chinese PSU because I've seen the Chinese letters on it. I just had a question if I can upgrade my pc to Asus GTX 750Ti 2 GB OC.

My pc specs are:

- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 3.0 GHZ
- 250GB HDD
- Onboard graphics card

Answer (score 0):

> I just had a question if I can upgrade my pc to Asus GTX 750 Ti 2 GB OC.

Yes;  The power requirements for a stock [GTX 750 Ti](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications) is only **60 W** with a recommendation of a **300 W** PSU.

> - Graphics Card Power (W) - 60 W
> - Minimum System Power Requirement (W) - 300 W

[Specifications](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications)

While the [Intel Core 2 Duo E8400](https://ark.intel.com/products/33910/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8400-6M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) has a TDP of only **65 W**.  While I wouldn't suggest you use a cheap PSU, it would only be a suggestion not to use a cheap generic PSU, and it's only an opinion due to the many bad experiences I had with generic parts.